# More direct way to create list of dataframes from XML file?

Tags: xml, r, xpath, lapply

[SDMX](http://sdmx.org/) (Statistical Data and Metadata Exchange) is a 'XML' grammar that defines a standard for exchanging statistical data. It uses  files called Dataset Structure Definition Description (DSD) to convey the structure of a dataset. Amongst other things the DSD contains a node `Codelists` that is comprised of the `Codelist` items which in turn  are parent to  the `Code` and `Name` item and attribuet. I am currently trying to parse these Codelists of a DSD file requested from [Eurostats REST interface](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/sdmx_web_services/getting_started/rest_sdmx_2.1) into a list of dataframes in R using the following code:

```
library(XML);library(RCurl)

# REST resource for DSD of nama_gdp_c
# downloading, parsing XML an setting root
file <- "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/datastructure/ESTAT/DSD_nama_gdp_c"
content <- getURL(file, httpheader = list('User-Agent' = 'R-Agent'))
root <- xmlRoot(xmlInternalTreeParse(content, useInternalNodes = TRUE))

# get Nodeset of Codelists and its length
nodes <- getNodeSet(root,"//str:Codelist")
nn <- length(nodes)

# Create nested List of all Codes and Names
codelistAll <- lapply(seq(nn),function(i){
  xpathSApply(root,paste0("//str:Codelist[",i,"]/str:Code"),xmlGetAttr, "id")
})

namelistAll <- lapply(seq(nn),function(i){
  xpathSApply(root,paste0("//str:Codelist[",i,"]/str:Code/com:Name"),xmlValue)
})

# Create a list of dataframes from the nested lists
alldfList <-lapply(seq(nn),function(i) data.frame(codes=codelistAll[[i]],names=namelistAll[[i]]))

# Name the list items like the nodes
names(alldfList)  <- sapply(nodes, xmlGetAttr,"id")
```

This yields `alldfList`, the list of dataframes which I was looking for.

```
> str(alldfList)
List of 6
 $ CL_FREQ      :'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ codes: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","D","H","M",..: 2 6 5 1 4 3
  ..$ names: Factor w/ 6 levels "Annual","Daily",..: 2 6 4 1 3 5
 $ CL_GEO       :'data.frame':  49 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ codes: Factor w/ 49 levels "AT","BA","BE",..: 22 21 20 10 16 15 14 13 12 11 ...
  ..$ names: Factor w/ 49 levels "Austria","Belgium",..: 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 ...
```

While this does the job, I have the feeling that there must be a more straightforward syntax to achieve this. Especially the use of `paste0` and the final assignment of names seem awkward. I have been reading through the documentation of the `XML` package and I suspect it must be some operation on the `xlmChildren` but I cannot wrap my head around how to actually do it. Does anyone have a suggestion for a canonical way of doing this operation? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I always start with the ones that return the data, `xmlToDataFrame()`, `readHTMLTable()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data.frames directly from nodes, but need to use a namespace

```
ns <- c(str="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/structure")

alldfList <- lapply(nodes, function(x){ data.frame(
  codes= xpathSApply(x, ".//str:Code" , xmlGetAttr, "id", namespaces=ns),
  names= xpathSApply(x, ".//str:Code" , xmlValue, namespaces=ns) )})

names(alldfList)  <- sapply(nodes, xmlGetAttr,"id")
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm and is definitely more terse and compact than the code posted originally. It took me some minutes to understand that the namespace gets stripped from the original XML when using getNodeSet. Do you know by chance if there is a direct way of keeping the namespaces when subsetting the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to read SDMX-ML files in R, you can try the rsdmx package hosted in [Github](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx). The package is available for download in CRAN, and the latest version allows you to read Data Structure Definitions (DSDs) and components including Codelists, Concepts and KeyFamilies.

For installation, in case you can anyway easily install it from Github using the following:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("rsdmx", "opensdmx")
```

Taking your example for Codelists, you can easily coerce SDMX codelists to data.frame doing the following:

```
require(rsdmx)
file <- "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/datastructure/ESTAT/DSD_nama_gdp_c"
sdmx <- readSDMX(file)

#get the list of codelist Id
codelists <- sapply(sdmx@codelists, function(x) x@id)

#get some specific codelist as data.frame
codelist <- as.data.frame(sdmx, codelistId = "CL_GEO")
head(codelist)
```

Similar can be done for SDMX Concepts / ConceptSchemes, complete Data Structure Definitions (DSD), and for sure SDMX datasets. Check out more examples at [rsdmx wiki](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/wiki#examples).

Hope this helps!