# Convert XML file to a list of data-frames in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I have a dataset from [HMDB](https://hmdb.ca/downloads) the `Saliva Metabolites` data. This data is XML file. What I want to do is to convert this XML file to a list of data-frames in R, however, I don't want all the nodes in the list.

Importing the file and converting to a list:

```
require(XML)
library("methods")
data <- xmlParse("D:/rout/to/my/downloaded/file/saliva_metabolites/saliva_metabolites.xml")

xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
```

Now, not sure how to select specific nodes. **Meaning, my goal is to create a list of metabolites and each metabolite from the list will have a list of data frames**. Say `<metabolite>` then `<accession>` as a string   then `<name>` as a sting  and `<synonym>` all synonyms as a data-frame.

Using this question [More direct way to create a list of data frames from XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929109/more-direct-way-to-create-list-of-dataframes-from-xml-file)
but the link to the data in the question is not working and I don't understand how to implement it in my code.

I tried this question code [xml to R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737989/xml-to-r-dataframe) to select specific nodes but it didn't work

```
x <- lapply(data["//metabolite"], XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame)
```

but this gave me an empty list

```
> x
list()
```

Any hints, references or help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is a code sample for the first three metabolites, and two of their child-nodes..

```
library( xml2 )
library( magrittr )  #for pipe operator %>%

doc <- read_xml( "./temp/saliva_metabolites.xml" )
#get metabolite nodes (only first three used in this sample)
met.nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//d1:metabolite" )[1:3]
#list of data.frames with secondary accessions
# only two in this sample
xpath_child.v <- c( "./d1:secondary_accessions/d1:accession",
                    "./d1:synonyms/d1:synonym" )
#what names should they get in the list?
child.names.v <- c( "secondary_accessions",
                    "synonyms" )
#first, loop over the met.nodes
L.sec_acc <- lapply( met.nodes, function(x) { 
  #second, loop over the xpath desired child-nodes
  temp <- lapply( xpath_child.v, function(y) { 
    xml_find_all(x, y ) %>% xml_text() %>% data.frame( value = .)
    })
  #set their names
  names(temp) = child.names.v
  return(temp)
  }) 
#set names of metabolites
names(L.sec_acc) <- xml_find_first( met.nodes, ".//d1:name ") %>% xml_text()
```

**output**

```
# $`1-Methylhistidine`
# $`1-Methylhistidine`$secondary_accessions
# value
# 1   HMDB00001
# 2 HMDB0004935
# 3 HMDB0006703
# 4 HMDB0006704
# 5   HMDB04935
# 6   HMDB06703
# 7   HMDB06704
# 
# $`1-Methylhistidine`$synonyms
# value
# 1  (2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoic acid
# 2                                         1-Methylhistidine
# 3                                        Pi-methylhistidine
# 4      (2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoate
# 5                                         1 Methylhistidine
# 6                                        1-Methyl histidine
# 7                                        1-Methyl-histidine
# 8                                      1-Methyl-L-histidine
# 9                                                    1-MHis
# 10                                   1-N-Methyl-L-histidine
# 11                                      L-1-Methylhistidine
# 12                                    N1-Methyl-L-histidine
# 13                        1-Methylhistidine dihydrochloride
# 
# 
# $`2-Ketobutyric acid`
# $`2-Ketobutyric acid`$secondary_accessions
# value
# 1   HMDB00005
# 2 HMDB0006544
# 3   HMDB06544
# 
# $`2-Ketobutyric acid`$synonyms
# value
# 1                  2-Ketobutanoic acid
# 2                    2-Oxobutyric acid
# 3                3-Methyl pyruvic acid
# 4                   alpha-Ketobutyrate
# 5               alpha-Ketobutyric acid
# 6             alpha-oxo-N-Butyric acid
# 7                      2-Ketobutanoate
# 8                       2-Ketobutyrate
# 9                        2-Oxobutyrate
# 10                   3-Methyl pyruvate
# 11                      a-Ketobutyrate
# 12                  a-Ketobutyric acid
# 13                      a-ketobutyrate
# 14                  a-ketobutyric acid
# 15                    a-oxo-N-Butyrate
# 16                a-oxo-N-Butyric acid
# 17                alpha-oxo-N-Butyrate
# 18                    a-oxo-N-butyrate
# 19                a-oxo-N-butyric acid
# 20                     2-oxo-Butanoate
# 21                 2-oxo-Butanoic acid
# 22                      2-oxo-Butyrate
# 23                  2-oxo-Butyric acid
# 24                    2-oxo-N-Butyrate
# 25                2-oxo-N-Butyric acid
# 26                      2-Oxobutanoate
# 27                  2-Oxobutanoic acid
# 28                    3-Methylpyruvate
# 29                3-Methylpyruvic acid
# 30                   a-keto-N-Butyrate
# 31               a-keto-N-Butyric acid
# 32                       a-Oxobutyrate
# 33                   a-Oxobutyric acid
# 34               alpha-keto-N-Butyrate
# 35           alpha-keto-N-Butyric acid
# 36               alpha-Ketobutric acid
# 37                   alpha-Oxobutyrate
# 38               alpha-Oxobutyric acid
# 39                     Methyl-pyruvate
# 40                 Methyl-pyruvic acid
# 41                   Propionyl-formate
# 42               Propionyl-formic acid
# 43 alpha-Ketobutyric acid, sodium salt
# 
# 
# $`2-Hydroxybutyric acid`
# $`2-Hydroxybutyric acid`$secondary_accessions
# value
# 1 HMDB00008
# 
# $`2-Hydroxybutyric acid`$synonyms
# value
# 1                               2-Hydroxybutanoic acid
# 2                           alpha-Hydroxybutanoic acid
# 3                            alpha-Hydroxybutyric acid
# 4                                   2-Hydroxybutanoate
# 5                                    2-Hydroxybutyrate
# 6                                   a-Hydroxybutanoate
# 7                               a-Hydroxybutanoic acid
# 8                               alpha-Hydroxybutanoate
# 9                                   a-hydroxybutanoate
# 10                              a-hydroxybutanoic acid
# 11                                   a-Hydroxybutyrate
# 12                               a-Hydroxybutyric acid
# 13                               alpha-Hydroxybutyrate
# 14                                   a-hydroxybutyrate
# 15                               a-hydroxybutyric acid
# 16                              (RS)-2-Hydroxybutyrate
# 17                          (RS)-2-Hydroxybutyric acid
# 18                                 2-Hydroxy-butanoate
# 19                             2-Hydroxy-butanoic acid
# 20                               2-Hydroxy-DL-butyrate
# 21                           2-Hydroxy-DL-butyric acid
# 22                                2-Hydroxy-N-butyrate
# 23                            2-Hydroxy-N-butyric acid
# 24                                a-Hydroxy-N-butyrate
# 25                            a-Hydroxy-N-butyric acid
# 26                            alpha-Hydroxy-N-butyrate
# 27                        alpha-Hydroxy-N-butyric acid
# 28                               DL-2-Hydroxybutanoate
# 29                           DL-2-Hydroxybutanoic acid
# 30                                DL-a-Hydroxybutyrate
# 31                            DL-a-Hydroxybutyric acid
# 32                            DL-alpha-Hydroxybutyrate
# 33                        DL-alpha-Hydroxybutyric acid
# 34                   2-Hydroxybutyric acid, (R)-isomer
# 35              2-Hydroxybutyric acid, monosodium salt
# 36                  2-Hydroxybutyric acid, (+-)-isomer
# 37 2-Hydroxybutyric acid, monosodium salt, (+-)-isomer
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! If ok, I'd like to ask about the child-nodes. you mention 2 child-nodes  and this is what i see in your code: secondary_accessions and synonyms. however it the outputs it looks like there is anthor one - name. howcome? my second question is about syntax, what is the "./d1: " ?  [Iooked and the xml2 docoument](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/xml2.pdf) but didn't find any explantion

Comment: `./d1:` defines the xml-namespace the nodes are in..  see: https://rdrr.io/cran/xml2/man/xml_ns.html Not sure what you mean with another name? The name of the metabolite itself?

Comment: looks like `pathways`is inside node `biological_properties`... you have to declare the complete path, or use `.//` for . see http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html, example 1 and 2

Comment: The link is excellent thank you! I'd like to ask one more question, I'm trying to create a list of diseases names (from the nodes diseases>disease>name) and each disease will contain another list with all pubmed_id values (from the nodes diseases>disease>references>reference>pubmed_id),  where _references_ node is in the same level as _name_ node [I tried this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007689/xml-parser-in-r-with-hierarchical-nodes-tags-and-values)  with your code but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option :

```
### packages

library(XML)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

### xml parse

xml <- xmlTreeParse("C://Users/.../saliva_metabolites/saliva_metabolites.xml",useInternalNode=TRUE)

### get the context nodes

ns <- getNodeSet(xml, "//*[local-name()='metabolite']")

### rbind the results of a function which extracts the data in order to construct the df

df=rbindlist(lapply(ns, function(x) {
  nm = xpathSApply(x,"(.//*[local-name()='name'])[1]",xmlValue)
  acc = xpathSApply(x,"(.//*[local-name()='accession'])[1]",xmlValue)
  syn = xpathSApply(x,"(.//*[local-name()='synonyms'])[1]/*",xmlValue)
  data.frame(name=nm,accession=acc,synonyms = paste(syn, collapse = '¤'))}), fill=TRUE)

### put synonyms of each row in a list (not mandatory)

df$synonyms = lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$synonyms),split='¤'),trimws)

## adding NA where the result is blank for synonyms and export the dfs (1 for each metabolite)

outp = df %>% mutate(synonyms=na_if(synonyms, "")) %>% group_split(xml_pos=row_number())
```

Output (3 first results) :

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name              accession   synonyms   xml_pos
  <chr>             <chr>       <list>       <int>
1 1-Methylhistidine HMDB0000001 <chr [13]>       1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name               accession   synonyms   xml_pos
  <chr>              <chr>       <list>       <int>
1 2-Ketobutyric acid HMDB0000005 <chr [43]>       2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name                  accession   synonyms   xml_pos
  <chr>                 <chr>       <list>       <int>
1 2-Hydroxybutyric acid HMDB0000008 <chr [37]>       3
```

Comment: Thank you, E.Wiest! I would like to ask another question if ok. If I want to create a list of diseases_name (from the nodes diseases> diseases >name) and each name will contain a list of  pubmed_id values ( (from node diseases> diseases >references >pubmed_id ) where the _references_  node and the  _name_ nodes are siblings nodes, is it possible?